# sql server convert datetime

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have the following code to convert datetime to format as 29 Disember 2014

```
RIGHT('0' + DATENAME(DAY, ta.startdate), 2) 
    + ' ' 
    + DATENAME(MONTH, ta.startdate)
    + ' ' 
    + DATENAME(YEAR, ta.startdate) AS [DD Month YYYY] as startdate
```

but the statement are incorrect syntax because I put as startdate at the back, I guess sql statement not accept two words of 'AS'. Are there any way so that I can declare the statement as startdate? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not using `DATE_FORMAT(ta.startdate, "%d %M %Y") AS startdate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the first alias:

```
(RIGHT('0' + DATENAME(DAY, ta.startdate), 2) + ' ' +
 DATENAME(MONTH, ta.startdate) + ' ' +
 DATENAME(YEAR, ta.startdate)
) as startdate
```